# Store for loop results in array

Tags: julia

I'm trying to store the results of a for loop in an array.  My loop looks like this:

```
MaleBaseTable=Matrix(MaleTable)
function MaleSurvCurve(i,j)
    resize!(diag(@view MaleBaseTable[i:end,j:end]),121)
end

year = 13
MaleQxs = for i in age_attained
    local j = year
    println(MaleSurvCurve(i,j))
end
```

This is printing the results that I want, but I can't do anything with them. I've tried the suggestions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037732/how-to-save-julia-for-loop-returns-in-an-array-or-dataframe) but can't get them to work:

```
MaleSurvCurve(convert(Array)) for i in age_attained
```

But this gives me "ERROR: syntax: extra token "for" after end of expression", closing the for with an end statement doesn't work either.

I'm also struggling with the map suggestion `map(i->MaleSurvCurve(convert(Array, i)), eachrow(iris[1:4]))` which tells me I can't convert int64 to Arrays.

Any suggestions please? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely, but you want to get the output of `MaleSurvCurve(i,j)` for various input values, and store them in an array?

The simplest solution is to use dot-broadcasting:

```
Arr = MaleSurvCurve.(age_attained, year)
```

You could also use an array comprehension:

```
Arr = [MaleSurvCurv(i, j) for i in age_attained, j in year]
# or for a fixed year
Arr = [MaleSurvCurv(i, year) for i in age_attained]
```

Pre-allocating an array and then filling it would also work

```
Arr = zeros(Float64, length(age_attained)) # if the output is expected to be floats
for (i, age) in enumerate(age_attained)
    Arr[i] = MaleSurvCurv(age, year)
end
```

I recommend broadcasting, though, it is both the simplest and most general solution. No need to worry about the sizes and shapes of the inputs, the input/output types of `MaleSurvCurv`, etc. It is also very efficient.

Brief note: if you have both a vector for `age_attained` and `year`, you actually need to do

```
Arr = MaleSurvCurve.(age_attained, year')
```

that is, transpose `year` to get a matrix of all combinations, so that's a small complication.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
MaleQxs = [MaleSurvCurve(i, year) for i in age_attained]
```

or this

```
MaleQxs = map(i -> MaleSurvCurve(i, year), age_attained)
```